# What is the difference between @Inject and @Autowired

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

i am just wondering what is the difference between @Inject & @Autowired
when to use each one ?, or they are doing the same thing ?

and if i have a spring bean which have a scope:

```
@Service
@Scope("singleton")
```

can i make dependency injection for it with both with no problems ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I know, they do the same. @Inject is an annotation from javax.inject, which is only the API for dependency injection. In Spring you can use both, as I think Spring provides an implementation for @Inject which does the same thing as @Autowired in Spring environments.

Matthias Wessendorf blogged about this here: http://matthiaswessendorf.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/spring-3-0-and-jsr-330-part-2/

Answer (score 6):

How about reading [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html?bcsi_scan_554E00F99A9AD604=qR0BnBJYdYhkunf4QHh96xxReNkrAAAAr1HHCA==&bcsi_scan_filename=spring-framework-reference.html#beans-autowired-annotation)?

> JSR 330's @Inject annotation can be used in place of Spring's
>   @Autowired in the examples below. @Inject does not have a required
>   property unlike Spring's @Autowired annotation which has a required
>   property to indicate if the value being injected is optional. This
>   behavior is enabled automatically if you have the JSR 330 JAR on the
>   classpath.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is worth pointing out that, if you use `@Autowired`, you are creating a dependency on Spring, where using `@Inject`, you will be able to swap out another dependency injection framework that supports `JSR 330`.

Comment: Where do you need more clarification?

Comment: about using @Inject in a spring application, and if that's a problem or bad practice ?

Answer (score 0):

**First**, @Autowired is defined by Spring Framework but @Inject came from "Dependency Injection for Java" (JSR-330)"

**Second**, @Inject doesn't take required attribute so if it fails to find any bean, it will fail with an error but @Autowired can come with required=false and will allow a nullable field.

**Third**, Advantage of @Inject annotation is that rather than inject a reference directly, you could ask @Inject to inject a Provider. The Provider interface enables, among other things, lazy injection of bean references and injection of multiple instances of a bean.